# Indexing a single dimensional array with a double for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

This should be something simple to do and I should know this, but I'm at a blank.

```
struct Coords {
    unsigned row;
    unsigned col;
};

Coords indexTable[256];

for ( unsigned row = 0; row < 16; ++row ) {
    for ( unsigned col = 0; col < 16; ++col ) {
        unsigned currIndex = ?
        indexTable[currIndex].row = something;
        indexTable[currIndex].col = something;
    }
}
```

What is the calculation for the current index? currIndex would be the same as traversing through [0,255] in a single for loop.

Comment: `row * 16 + col`, or `row * NCOLS + col` if you have `NCOLS` columns.

Comment: for example, calculate the offset for start of current row. add offset to column in that row. but this is just one of the two main possibilities, plus there are an unbounded number of less natural possibilities. for a proper answer you need to **define** what you want the `currIndex` to be.

Comment: If you have searched and found the opposite, don't you think you're doing the opposite? Please state your problem clearly, if otherwise.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf the current Indexing is incremental as if traversing through the `indexTable[]` with a single for loop, I wanted a double for loop for readability with the row and column relationship. Imagine traversing through a grid 16x16, and the coordinates would be (0,0) ...  (15,15). In my source I'm using byte (unsigned char) for row and col, and in hex value row & col range from [0x00, 0x0F] this is stored into indexTable[256]. I also have another array[256] that holds bytes as well. These values are the compression of the two using bit shifting and masking so [0x03,0x0C] = [0x3C],

Comment: When column index varies fastest as you scan through the array, Holt's comment (and my earlier comment) shows how to compute the `indexTable`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf (...continued) so my first array of pairs would be populatd like this:  [0] = (0,0), [1] = (0,1) .... [255] = (15,15)... and after the doing the bit manipulation my second array would be like this: [0] = 0x00, 0x01 ... 0xFF

Comment: I had a one point thought of that, but when I was working out the math it didn't seem to me like it was right. Yes I up voted his comment.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your help; at one point I did have the right equation, but when I was doing the math to check it, I was messing up on the math so I end up abandoning it. Could be because I'm getting tired and its been a fairly long night.

Comment: you are incrementing `col` in both for loops, `unsigned row = 0; row < 16; ++col` should be `unsigned row = 0; row < 16; ++row`

Comment: @Jonas yes thank you for pointing out the typo!

Comment: I did mention I was tired didn't I? LOL well almost done for the night, not too much longer to go.

Answer (score 0):

Provided by Holt and Cheers and hth. - Alf from the comments they have answered this question.

```
currIndex =  row * 16 + col;
```

I did have this earlier but when I was doing the math to verify, I made a mistake in the math so I ended up abandoning it.